# Integrating streamlit with Docker not working

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to integrate Streamlit with Docker. Means, I am trying to make a container where the python code is using streamlit.

The app.py is:

```
import streamlit as st

st.title("Hello Streamlit")
st.header("Calculate % Growth")
initial = st.number_input("Initial investment in USD")
yr = st.number_input("Growth Period in years")
growth = st.number_input("Growth Rate in %")
terminal_value = 0
current_val = initial
for year in range(int(yr)):
   current_val += growth * current_val
   terminal_value = current_val

# perform cashflow projections for the next 5 years
st.write(f'Terminal value of {initial} after {yr} years at a growth rate of {growth} is {terminal_value}')
```

When I run it with streamlit run app.py, it runs perfectly in the localhost.

Now, I have a Dockerfile. It is:

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# copy project
COPY . . 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8501
CMD streamlit run app.py
```

I build the image as:

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

The next step is running the container from the image. It is:

```
docker run  myimage
```

It gives this output in the terminal:

```
  You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser.

  Network URL: http://172.17.0.3:8501
  External URL: http://79.255.36.161:8501
```

However, when I go to the localhost, it gives "Hmmm... can't reach this page".

I dont know why it is not working. I am new in Docker. I am using a windows machine (although I dont think it is the problem).

Thanks to all.

Comment: have you tried to hit `http://172.17.0.3:8501`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://localhost:8501/` instead of `http://172.17.0.3:8501`

That worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use EXPOSE 8501
ENV PORT=8501

CMD streamlit run chatbot.py --server.port $PORT

it helped me , I was also getting the same error

Comment: add code blocks